# Done button in game center leader-board doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios7, delegates, leaderboard

When i press done button in leaderboard view, it doesn't do anything and leaderboard is still visible.

here is code:

```
GKGameCenterViewController *gcViewController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];

gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
[gcViewController setDelegate:self ];
if (shouldShowLeaderboard) {
    gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = currentLeaderBoard;
}
else{
    gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements;
}

[self presentViewController:gcViewController animated:YES completion:nil];**
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you must add the function to dismiss the view controller (to delegate)

```
-(void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController{
[gameCenterViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to add  `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` to the protocol list.